# vba to sort the data into matrix form

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I have some data, for the first column date, it contains two dates.

Then I have the fund code and the categories, the last column is the categories value.

How shall I put them into matrix format, for example, the categories is horizontal and the value correspond to the fund name and categories and the date.

Comment: thank you very much for your reading and help

Comment: Is this for the best screen layout or best structure to store the data. Can you upload some type of screenshot to your question.

Comment: I want it to display like this (you can refer to my question picture) for column A, display one date, for column 2, display the fund code, and then the categories is the header, then post the values accordingly

Comment: thank you please help me

Comment: Are you okay with solution using formulas?

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, actually I can use index and match function to do the sorting, but I would like to appeal to all data, thats why I need the vba, thanks in advance

Comment: Sorting alone is not the solution. Output you are looking for can also be achieved using formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code should be helpful.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False             'stop screen flickering
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual  'prevent calculation while execution
    End With

    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, tblLastRow As Long, tblLastColumn As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim rng As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range, dateRng, fundCodeRng As Range, categoryRng As Range, valueRng As Range

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  'change Sheet1 to your worksheet

    With ws
        lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   'get last row with data
        'set ranges for date, fund code, category and value to be used later in code
        Set dateRng = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
        Set fundCodeRng = .Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
        Set categoryRng = .Range("C2:C" & lastrow)
        Set valueRng = .Range("D2:D" & lastrow)

        'get unique records for date and fund coding combined together
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value & "|" & .Cells(i, 2).Value) = dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value & "|" & .Cells(i, 2).Value)
        Next

        With .Range("F2").Resize(dict.Count)    'date and fund code will be displayed from cell F2
            .Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells, DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
            .Offset(, 2).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)
        End With

        'empty dictionary
        dict.RemoveAll
        Set dict = Nothing
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        'get unique categories and display as header
        rng = .Range("C1:C" & lastrow)
        For i = 2 To UBound(rng)
            dict(rng(i, 1) & "") = ""
        Next
        .Range("H1").Resize(1, UBound(dict.Keys()) + 1).Value = dict.Keys   'categories will be displayed from column H

        tblLastRow = .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row             'get last row in new table
        tblLastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column    'get last column of category in new table

        'display corresponding values for date, fund code and category
        For Each cel In .Range(.Cells(2, 8), .Cells(tblLastRow, tblLastColumn)) 'Cells(2, 8) represent Cell("H2")
            cel.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(" & valueRng.Address & ",MATCH(1,(" & dateRng.Address & "=" & .Cells(cel.Row, 6) & ")*(" & fundCodeRng.Address & "=""" & .Cells(cel.Row, 7) & """)*(" & categoryRng.Address & "=""" & .Cells(1, cel.Column) & """),0)),"""")"
            cel.Value = cel.Value
        Next cel

    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

See image for reference.

[image]
***EDIT :***

---

If *Fund Code* could be numbers also then replace

```
cel.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(" & valueRng.Address & ",MATCH(1,(" & dateRng.Address & "=" & .Cells(cel.Row, 6) & ")*(" & fundCodeRng.Address & "=""" & .Cells(cel.Row, 7) & """)*(" & categoryRng.Address & "=""" & .Cells(1, cel.Column) & """),0)),"""")"
```

with

```
cel.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(" & valueRng.Address & ",MATCH(1,(" & dateRng.Address & "=" & .Cells(cel.Row, 6) & ")*(Text(" & fundCodeRng.Address & ",""0"")=""" & .Cells(cel.Row, 7) & """)*(" & categoryRng.Address & "=""" & .Cells(1, cel.Column) & """),0)),"""")"
```

Comment: yes, I endorsed your answer, btw, how can I display the data of two dates parallel. So than I could have better comparison

Comment: and one more error is that when the fund name is in all digits, like 123456, the sorting will not show the results, leaving the area to be blank.

Comment: @HKU_Johnny_QFin - See edit in my answer. For `how can I display the data of two dates parallel`, you need to give more details.

Comment: thank you so much. the things I would like to achieve is that for one date, the data would be posted in columns (in this case, from F to L) and I would like data of another data to display after column L

Comment: @HKU_Johnny_QFin - That's a huge work around. Completely new logic needs to be written for what you are asking.